# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array => still getting error after fixing json_encode

Tags: php

I need to reorganize my JSON and i'm using `StdClass()` yet getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

I have looked at other questions re this before posting here, yet I've found that the true option is needed, which I've already amended, yet no success.

This is my function:

```
function getFilesJson($fileArray){
    $arrayOfStudentFiles = [];
    foreach ($fileArray as $key => $file){
        $outObj = new StdClass;
        $tmpFileObject = new StdClass;
        $outObj->files = [];

        $tmpFileObject->name = $fileArray[$key]['sequence']->name;
        $tmpFileObject->compiled = true;
        $tmpFileObject->lineNumbers = $fileArray[$key]['sequence']->lineNumbers;
        $tmpFileObject->sequence = $fileArray[$key]['sequence']->sequence;
        $tmpFileObject->defTerms = $fileArray[$key]['sequence']->defTerms;
        $outObj->files[0] = $tmpFileObject;

        $outObj->filesMotifs = [];
        $outObj->fileName = "{$fileArray[$key]->name}.zip";
        $outObj->unknowns = $fileArray[$key]['sequence']->unknowns;
        $outObj->motifs = [];
        $outObj->clusters = [];
        $outObj->objects = [];

        if (isset($fileArray[$key]->objects))
            $outObj->objects = $fileArray[$key]->objects;

        $arrayOfStudentFiles[] = json_encode($outObj, true);
    }
    return $arrayOfStudentFiles;
}
```

> EDIT: `$fileArray` is an array of stdClass's

Answer (score 0):

Change your final output as Array instead of object like,

```
function getFilesJson($fileArray){
    $arrayOfStudentFiles = [];
    foreach ($fileArray as $key => $file){
        $outObj = [];
        $tmpFileObject = [];
        $outObj['files'] = [];

        $tmpFileObject['name'] = $file['sequence']['name'];
        $tmpFileObject['compiled'] = true;
        $tmpFileObject['lineNumbers'] = $file['sequence']['lineNumbers'];
        $tmpFileObject['sequence'] = $file['sequence']['sequence'];
        $tmpFileObject['defTerms'] = $file['sequence']['defTerms'];
        $outObj[files[0]] = $tmpFileObject;

        $outObj['filesMotifs'] = [];
        $outObj['fileName'] = "{$file['name']}.zip";
        $outObj['unknowns'] = $file['sequence']['unknowns'];
        $outObj['motifs'] = [];
        $outObj['clusters'] = [];
        $outObj['objects'] = [];

        if (isset($file['objects']))
            $outObj['objects'] = $file['objects'];

        $arrayOfStudentFiles[] = json_encode($outObj, true);
    }
    return $arrayOfStudentFiles;
}
```

Comment: I just edited the question and added that `$fileArray` is an array of stdClass's.
So I'm still getting the error

Comment: @senseCode add `$fileArray` array output please.

Comment: ok, just add a line right at the beginning inside the foreach and the answer is yours:
`$file = json_decode(json_encode($file),true);`